# How is it (is it?) possible to prevent the PivotTablization of data to result in "#DIV/0!" and such when there is missing data?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

I am generating a PivotTable which is comprised of monthly data for items (how many of this sold, how many of that sold, and related statistics). In some cases, though, there are no sales for a particular item in one or more months. In that case, there is no record that contains a "0" value, the record simply does not exist for the non-existent sale.

When such an item's data is displayed, the nonexistent data wreaks havoc. The screen shot below shows what happens when an item does have data for both months (APPLES, GALA 5#), and when it doesn't (APPLES, GALA 5#):

[image]

So as you can see, when the data is PivotTablized, rather than put a "0" in "Total Packages" and "Total Purchases" it leaves those cells blank and inserts a "#DIV/0!" in the "Sum of Average Price" cell - and then a "." in the "% of Total" cell.

This is not helpful or pleasing to the eye. I would like either a series of dashes in those cells or zeroes.

A workaround would be to create a row for each currently non-existent one in the source pivot data, but that seems unnecessary and kludgy in the extreme - I would have to determine which items had "missing" months and then supply them with those 0 values.

Is this really what I need to do? Please say it ain't so!

### UPDATE

The proffered answer led me to experiment with what would happen by changing the PivotTable options Format vals. With this data to begin:

[image]

...I entered a question mark for err vals, and a dash for empty cells:

[image]

This caused the data to look like so:

[image]

Better, but still not quite what I want/expect. Since it's better, at least, I'd settle for a programmatic way to accomplish the same thing.

I wasn't expecting to see the "?" following some of the "good" values, though...

So what I may need is the programmatic equivalent of "for empty cells, show a dash" (which converts to 0 for int and $0 for decimal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivot Tables can hide errors.

Right-click on your Pivot Table and select *Pivot Table options*. On the *Layout and Format* tab, under *Format*, look for *For error values show*.

[image: Pivot Table error handling]

Comment: How could this be done (preventively) programmatically? Users won't want to mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect ("pvt" is the PivotTable):

```
pvt.ErrorString = "";
pvt.DisplayErrorString = true;
```

...but it does blank out (except for a recalcitrant "." in the %" cell) the missing values:

[image]

I added another line of code to see what it would do:

```
pvt.NullString = "-";
```

...so I now have this:

```
pvt.ErrorString = "";
pvt.DisplayErrorString = true;
pvt.NullString = "-";
```

...and adding that last line did help - I get the "0" for ints and "$0" for decimals like so:

[image]